# how Can I inherit the widgets from a class and use them on my toplevel without rewriting a code

Tags: class, tkinter

hi I am currently developing an app, but I decided to look at classes, so I've re-coded some of it, as I must use a toplevel with exactly the same widgets as the main Tk. But my expectations of using inheritance doesn't seem to work.

BTW it is not an indentation error, this is the first time I've used Stackoverflow to ask a question so it seems to have unintended some of the code when I copied

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

    class MainWindow(Tk):
       def __init__(self,master,*args):
    self.master = master
    Tk.__init__(self,master,*args)
    self.notebook=ttk.Notebook(self)
    self.notebook.grid()

    #Creating frames
    def widgets(self):
        self.main_frame=Frame(self.notebook)
        self.searching_frame=Frame(self.notebook)
        self.img_frame=Frame(self.main_frame,height=60,width=40)
        self.data_frame=Frame(self.main_frame,height=90,width=90)
        self.data_frame.config(bg='orange')
        self.notebook.add(self.main_frame,text='main frame')
        self.notebook.add(self.searching_frame,text='Frame two')

        #Pack frames

        self.data_frame.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.img_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)


        #Creating widgets
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.img_frame,height=200,width=300,bg='skyblue')
        self.f_name_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="First name:")
        self.l_name_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Last name:")
        self.email_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Email:")
        self.phone_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Phone:")
        self.address_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Address:")
        self.price_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Price:")
                self.description_entry=Text(self.img_frame,height=10,width=45,relief=SUNKEN,wrap=WORD)

        #Pack the widgets
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.f_name_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
        self.l_name_lbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=20)
        self.email_lbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=20)
        self.phone_lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
        self.address_lbl.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=20)
        self.price_lbl.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20)
        self.description_entry.grid(row=2,column=0)


        #Creating entries
        self.f_name_entry=Entry(self.data_frame) #creates an entry for 'first name'
        self.l_name_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.email_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.phone_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.address_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.price_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
         self.description_entry=Text(self.img_frame,height=10,width=45,relief=SUNKEN,wrap=WORD)

        #Pack the entries
        self.f_name_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.l_name_entry.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.email_entry.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.phone_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5)
        self.address_entry.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.price_entry.grid(row=5,column=1)

        self.newwindow=Button(self.data_frame,text='New window',command=window_2)
        self.newwindow.grid(row=6,column=0,columnspan=2)

    widgets(self)



      app=MainWindow(None)
      app.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can only go by the code that is posted, and the code that is posted has indentation errors. Please take the time to present the code properly formatted.

Comment: Step 1) Copy and paste code into question. Step 2) Highlight the code. Step 3) Press Ctrl+K.This should serve to copy your code without losing indention.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job? You will have to fill out the `window_2` method but apart from that, it is all there. EDIT - I have removed the need for a `window_2` method or class by making the class directly call itself:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self,master,*args):
        self.master = master
        Tk.__init__(self,master,*args)
        self.notebook=ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.notebook.grid()
        self.widgets ()
        self.focus_force()

    #Creating frames
    def widgets(self):
        self.main_frame=Frame(self.notebook)
        self.searching_frame=Frame(self.notebook)
        self.img_frame=Frame(self.main_frame,height=60,width=40)
        self.data_frame=Frame(self.main_frame,height=90,width=90)
        self.data_frame.config(bg='orange')
        self.notebook.add(self.main_frame,text='main frame')
        self.notebook.add(self.searching_frame,text='Frame two')

        #Pack frames

        self.data_frame.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.img_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)


        #Creating widgets
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.img_frame,height=200,width=300,bg='skyblue')
        self.f_name_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="First name:")
        self.l_name_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Last name:")
        self.email_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Email:")
        self.phone_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Phone:")
        self.address_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Address:")
        self.price_lbl=Label(self.data_frame,text="Price:")
        self.description_entry=Text(self.img_frame,height=10,width=45,relief=SUNKEN,wrap=WORD)

        #Pack the widgets
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.f_name_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
        self.l_name_lbl.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=20)
        self.email_lbl.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=20)
        self.phone_lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
        self.address_lbl.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=20)
        self.price_lbl.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20)
        self.description_entry.grid(row=2,column=0)


        #Creating entries
        self.f_name_entry=Entry(self.data_frame) #creates an entry for 'first name'
        self.l_name_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.email_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.phone_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.address_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.price_entry=Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.description_entry=Text(self.img_frame,height=10,width=45,relief=SUNKEN,wrap=WORD)

        #Pack the entries
        self.f_name_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.l_name_entry.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.email_entry.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.phone_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5)
        self.address_entry.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.price_entry.grid(row=5,column=1)

        self.newwindow=Button(self.data_frame,text='New window',command=lambda:MainWindow(None))
        self.newwindow.grid(row=6,column=0,columnspan=2)

app=MainWindow(None)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your help, I was able to successfully copy the widgets to my Second window by using

        'class window_2(Toplevel,MainWindow):
            def __init__(self):
                Toplevel.__init__(self)
                MainWindow.widgets(self)'
obviously this doesn't format but you can still see :)

Comment: I have edited my answer based on what you have suggested to hopefully make it more efficient (also, for some reason I couldn't get your code to work).